# Cognos: Connect to PostgreSQL by ODBC

Tags: postgresql, odbc, connection-string, connect, cognos

I am trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database on my cognos framework manager.

Since there is no default connection for this, i'm trying to connect by ODBC.

But what is the connection string here? I have tried the following:

```
DRIVER={PostgreSQL};DATABASE=my_database_name;SERVER=my_server_name;UID=my_user_name;
PWD=my_user_password;
```

But when I try this it gives an error that I can't use semi-icons in the connection string.

What is the correct connection string then?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you created a machine data source name against your PostgreSQL database from the ODBC manager? do that first and test it. Then just use the name of your DSN with the ODBC data source type.